# Is there an AC to DC converter in LED strings used in home

Tags: led

In this basic electric circuit, current from `DC` power source goes to positive leg of an LED and then back to the battery

[image]

So LED is working on DC current.

But homes have AC power. Then how do the following LED strings work? Do they convert AC to DC first?

[image]

Comment: It depends. Some do, some don't. If the LEDs clearly flicker at mains frequency or at double the mains frequency, then there is just pulses, not DC. Please understand that we can't possibly know exactly how the lights in your picture work.

Comment: Most do but there are exceptions.

Comment: Keep in mind that the D in LED stands for diode.  In other words: a rectifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED string in your image should have some sort of power adaptor supplied with it. This will usually be in the form of a capacitor dropper followed by a rectifier.  The circuit may show various degrees of refinement.

- Input surge resistor to limit the inrush current.
- Discharge resistor across the capacitor
- Full wave bridge rectifier to increase the flicker frequency from 50 to 100Hz (or 60 to 120Hz)
- A smoothing / reservoir capacitor to reduce flicker further.

If you look on YouTube for "Big Clive", he has published numerous videos where he tears down LED lighting and explains the power supply circuits in detail.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/c/Bigclive